# Taking screenshot with selenium server 2.24.1 and firefox 13, when running MTAF

Tags: firefox, magento, testing, selenium, automation

I'm trying to set up my test automation engine. Unfortunately when I ran my tests and got failure no screen-shots are taken. I can't find any error in logs telling me what is wrong.

I'm using:
Magento Community 1.7.0.0,
Selenium-server 2.24.1,
Firefox 13.0.1,
PHPUnit 3.6.11,
Magento Tests Automation Framework (latest version).
Ubuntu 12.04

My questions are:
1. How to induce where the problem is?
2. Is there anybody who's succeed in screenshots on that firefox and selenium version?

Comment: perhaps selenium doesn't support firefox 13 :http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html

Comment: That link is outdated, [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) you can see Firefox 13 is supported. I take screenshots with it (with WebDriver) on a daily basis. However, I have no idea what Magento is. Could you do a simple test that opens Google and takes a screenshot to see what happens?

Comment: when I made test using Selenium IDE and run it (in Selenium IDE), I got screenshot. Magento is platform for eCommerce. MTAF is framework to making tests for shops created in Magento. MTAF use selenium to making test of Use Cases and run it by phpunit. I've made downgrade to firefox 10 and still zero screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple test without magento taf, which must fail:

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = TRUE;
    protected $screenshotPath = '/home/lpp2/Pulpit/report/';
    protected $screenshotUrl = '/home/lpp2/Pulpit/report/';

  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.pl/");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("http://www.google.pl/");
    $this->click("id=gbi4t");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->type("id=Email", "user.name");
    $this->type("id=Passwd", "pass");
    $this->click("id=signIn");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->assertEquals("Google", $this->getTitle());
  }
}
?>
```

My phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Google">
      <file>google.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
 <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./report/coverage/" charset="UTF-8"
         yui="true" highlight="false"
         lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="plain" target="./report/logfile.txt"/>
        <log type="junit" target="./report/logfile.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Got grate screenshot. So the problem is with magento taf. Something is disable. I found  in .../magento_taf/lib/Mage/Selenium/TestCase.php tree lines, which where commented:

```
protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = TRUE;
protected $screenshotPath = SELENIUM_TESTS_SCREENSHOTDIR;
protected $screenshotUrl = SELENIUM_TESTS_SCREENSHOTDIR;
```

Uncomment it -> Still not working!

Edit:
Ok, I've downloaded newest version from github and now it works.